# Adding index key in Grails' Domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I tried following this [reference](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html) and this is now my domain's code:

```
class SnbrActVector {

    long nid
    String term
    double weight

    static mapping = {
        version false
        nid index:'Nid_Idx'
    }

    static constraints = {
        term(blank:false)
    }
}
```

What I want is to do is to add an index key for the `nid` column. I dropped the existing table and ran the app again so the table is then recreated. However, when I check for list of indices, I can't see an `Nid_Idx`, only `PRIMARY`. Do I have to manually create the index and name it `Nid_idx` in my mysql database?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's working only when using `dbCreate = "create"`.

Let's say I have an empty database and my `dbCreate`  set to `"update"`. In this case index is not created.

Comment: Definitely is a bug in grails relative to its documentation. In section 4.3 it states "update - Creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data." Nonetheless, this old bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2152 states that it relates to a problem with Hibernate update and will not be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct so it might be another problem or a Grails bug.
My advice :

1. Create a new grails application (`grails create-app`) with `SnbrActVector` as the only domain (`grails create-domain...`). Copy your code inside.
2. Check that your *DataSource.groovy* file has `dbCreate = "create-drop"`
3. Verify the indices of the *SnbrActVector* table.

If you see an index created for `nid` column, then it means that there is problem in your application (you might not have used "create-drop" or something else)

If the index is NOT created => This is a grails bug and you should open a JIRA issue [here](https://cvs.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS)

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. it seems that there's a bug in grails 1.2.1 when using dbCreate = "update". it is not properly creating the index keys. it only works when using "create-drop", which is not recommended in prod env. note that after the index key was created by 'create-drop' and you change it back to 'update', the index key will be gone again.

Comment: It is not a bug.
I don't think that dbCreate = "update" should add/remove database indexes of existing columns (could be too dangerous in production mdoe). You can raise an issue on JIRA or ask for it in grails forum  (please post the link here).
Anyway, you have your answer. In development mode, you don't need to manually add index (using dbCreate = "create") but in production mode, if the database already exists, you have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the column name to get it to fire e.g.

```
static mapping = {
        version false
        nid column:'nid', index:'Nid_Idx'
    }
```

Comment: tested it and still not adding the index key automatically. pretty weird. btw, i'm using grails 1.2.1.